# MongoDB 4.4 - Collection data not distributed across shards

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a database with 3 shards and a collection called SearchTargets. I have an index on SearchTargetId which is not unique and have 500K records with SearchTargetId : 1 and another 500K with SearchtargetId: 25 and few hundred thousands with different Id's. After I Insert data using mongo restore, all data sitting on shard0002 even though I have two more shards shard0000 and shard0001. SearchTargetId is the shard key. The same configuration/setting with Mongo 4.0.12 distributed data between multiple shards (3 shards)

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you expect different behavior?

Comment: Sounds like a bad choice of sharding key. Have a look at [Choosing a Shard Key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/index.html#choosing-a-shard-key)

Comment: I am not expecting different behavior, but expecting the same behavior as it is in the 4.0.12 version. The one with 4.0.12 distributed 45%, 30% and 25% in each shard but in 4.4 version 100% records in shard0002 that I dont understand.

Comment: How did you determine the distribution?

Comment: Can you post the index you are having on collection ?

Comment: Here is the Index  @wak786
db.SearchTarget.createIndex({ SearchTargetId: 1 }, {});
sh.shardCollection("MyDb.SearchTarget", { "SearchTargetId": 1 });

Comment: `db.getCollection('SearchTarget').getShardDistribution()` and belowis the result                    `Shard shard0002 at mongo-2.mongo-service:27017
 data : 883.48MiB docs : 3182176 chunks : 0
 estimated data per chunk : InfinityGiB
 estimated docs per chunk : Infinity

Totals
 data : 883.48MiB docs : 3182176 chunks : 0
 Shard shard0002 contains 100% data, 100% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 291B`